# I need to remove extra double quotes from a file in linux

Tags: linux

Data

```
"ME SX","2017-05-05 18:33:22.000000","Gender","Gender","SX","2017-05-05 18:33:23.763951","ME SX","MembersEdge Sex Category" to Gender","ME"
```

Desired output

```
"ME SX","2017-05-05 18:33:22.000000","Gender","Gender","SX","2017-05-05 18:33:23.763951","ME SX","MembersEdge Sex Category to Gender","ME"
```

I'm using the following SED function

```
sed 's/\([^",]\)"\([^",]\)/\1\2/g;s/\([^",]\)""/\1"/g;s/""\([^",]\)/"\1/g'
```

When i use the above SED function i'm getting the output as below. There is a double quote missing at the end. need some help on this

```
"ME SX","2017-05-05 18:33:22.000000","Gender","Gender","SX","2017-05-05 18:33:23.763951","ME SX","MembersEdge Sex Category to Gender",**"ME**
```

Comment: Is there ever an instance in this data where a comma might be found inside double quotes?

Comment: Is it always the same field that can have an extra "? And only exactly one "? Could adding the last " if missing always work?

Comment: there wont be any comma inside the double quotes.

Comment: its not the same field every time which is having extra double quotes.

Comment: After i ran the SED function the last double quote was removed.